# Javadocs specifying issue number

Tags: java, comments, javadoc, issue-tracking

I got a issue, that wants to change functionaly in my java code, issue number for example #41241.

**What would be the correct Javadoc comment be to specify issue number, that requests this change?**

Just that in future I know, why a certain function or line was changed/created?

Comment: IMHO this depends on the Ticketing/Bug-Tracking-System. I usually do comments like `/** changed xyz for issue #123 */` or `/** as described in issue AB01-345, this needs to be changed to ... */` With the help of Mylyn this is really nice then as you can directly jump to the respective issue in your tracking system.

Comment: Beware of putting bug numbers in source code comments. It's what source control systems are for. In 6 months or so after you've added such comment, it becomes totally useless and obscures the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't write issue numbers into source code. This can get complicated when a method gets changed because of multiple issues...

I used to add the issue number to the SVN commit like: *ISSUE-1234: added NPE check*. Eclipse provides the useful feature `Team -> Show Annotations` which shows for each line in which SVN commit it was changed and the commit comment. This adds more benefit as a comment in JavaDoc in my opinion.